# Finding maximum value of a trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Let the function $f(x_1, x_2,x_3) = \cos(x_1-x_2) +\cos(x_2-x_3)+\cos(x_3-x_1)$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3$  are distinct real numbers.
Here, the value of minimum two cosine functions is going to be changed if I change the value of either one variable and which would then change the value of my whole function.
So, I can't say that it's maximum value would be $3$ since cosine function has a maximum value of $1$.
Then, how can we find the maximum values of these types of trigonometric functions which are dependent like these?

Comment: $x_1=x_2=x_3$ gives the value $3$, so $3$ is the maximum.

Comment: I want to find the distinct values of $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Comment: $x_1=0, x_2=2\pi, x_3=4\pi$ will do.

Comment: If you add the constraint that $~0 \leq x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < 2\pi,~$ then the problem becomes more interesting.  However, if you go that route, I request that you create a new posting, rather than editing this posting.  That is, it is not nice to ask MathSE reviewers to hit a moving target.

Comment: I forgot to mention that but actually $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are my polar coordinates and I want to take distinct points, so indirectly $0≤x_1, x_2, x_3≤2π$

Comment: I added it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602388/finding-maximum-value-of-a-trigonometric-functions

Comment: When $x_1<x_2<x_3$ but their value are very near, the equation approaches $3$.

Answer (score 1):

So, taking all your constraints, I will rewrite the question in my way as,

*f(x, y, z) = cos(x - y)+cos(y - z)+cos(z - x)*

Where, 0< x, y, z <2π

Let,
*x - y = A, y - z= B, &  z - x = -(A + B)*

*f(A, B) = cos(A) + cos(B) + cos(A + B)*

> As cos(-x) = cosx

> Keeping in mind that A can be equal to B

Where -2π< A, B <2π,
For maxima, A=B=0, but according to your constraint A,B≠0, so we can't take equility.

For minima, all 3 terms should be negative. And sum of their magnitude should be maximum. So,

*|cos(A)| = |cos(B)| = |cos(A + B)|*

> A consequence of AM-GM inequality

Taking magnitudes,

*|cos(k)| = |cos(2k)|*

So, as k can be 2π/3

> As maxima should be on every value of given family

*f(A,B) = 3×cos(2π/3) = -3/2*,

We are done!

*-3/2 ≤ f(A,B) < 3*